# Typesetting a big sum with index next to it

Tags: math-mode

How can I typeset a big summation with index next to it (like that one in the photo below) instead of an index in the bottom ?! . I need help please :) .

[image]

Comment: This yields a small summation not a big one . Besides, I use align environment.

Comment: `\sum\nolimits_{n}`

Comment: although this is most peculiar, it can be obtained by `\displaystyle]sum\nolimits_n`

Comment: I am deleting my earlier comment, since I misunderstood and provided a misleading comment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The place (above/below or right) for the indices of large operators can be set explicitly using `\limits` or `\nolimits`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
E &= \sum\nolimits_n f(x) \\
E &= 42
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle E=\sum\nolimits_n{f(x)}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This yields a small summation not a big one . Besides, I use align environment.