# Can I use subscript notation for summation in array/equation?

Tags: equations

Basically, can I get this

[image]

Rather than what `\[  \sum_{A \subset E}  () \]`  yields?  That is I want the equation not inline but also not have the subscript under a summation in order to save space.  I know you can use `\Sigma` instead but I'm told that `\Sigma` is smaller than `\sum`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typesetting a big sum with index next to it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338005/typesetting-a-big-sum-with-index-next-to-it)

Comment: Whatever else you do, don't use `\Sigma` to create a summation symbol. Not only do `\Sigma` and `\sum` look quite different, they also have different math status values -- `\Sigma` is math-ord`, whereas `\sum` is `math-op`. This affects the ability to typeset limits of summation.